Synapse - Developer Has Pause/Resume SQP Pool
A developer has reported they cant "Resume" a dedicated database via the Azure Portal as the menu option is greyed-out - see screen shot below.
I tried adding a Azure Entra group the developer is in to Synapse role "Synapse SQL Administrator" however this didn't work - any thoughts?



I am going to try the below...
It works nicely with:
Workspace RBAC: Reader
Dedicated Pool RBAC: Contributor
Workspace access control: Synapse User
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/1571397/unable-to-allow-basic-users-to-resume-synapse-dedi

This resolved the issue...
It works nicely with:
Workspace RBAC: Reader
Dedicated Pool RBAC: Contributor
Workspace access control: Synapse User
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/1571397/unable-to-allow-basic-users-to-resume-synapse-dedi
